# NguiTabModule is not an NgModule

Tags: angular, webpack

I got this error :

NguiTabModule is not an NgModule
webpack failed to compile

while trying to deploy my angular app in heroku.

I am using angular-cli
here is my package.json :

```
{
  "name": "myproject",
  "version": "4.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "prestart": "node-sass -r src/styles/themes -o temp/themes",
    "start": "ng serve --ec=true",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "postbuild": "node-sass -r src/styles/themes -o dist/themes",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "1.0.0-alpha.7",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^6.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "0.0.3",
    "angular2-toaster": "^3.0.1",
    "c3": "^0.4.11",
    "chart.js": "^2.5.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "fullcalendar": "^3.4.0",
    "jquery": "^2.1.0",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.5.0",
    "ng2-date-picker": "^1.4.2",
    "ng2-smart-table": "^1.1.0",
    "ngx-progressbar": "^2.0.0",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "^0.7.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.5",
    "angular2-jwt":"0.2.0",
    "ngx-loading" :"1.0.14 ",
    "ng2-auto-complete" :"0.12.0",
    "@ngui/tab" : "0.5.0",
    "@ngui/datetime-picker" : "0.16.2",
    "ngx-modal" :"0.0.29"



  },
  "devDependencies": {

    "@types/c3": "^0.4.41",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.2.0"
  }
}
```

and I import NguiTabModule in my app module like this :

```
 import { NguiTabModule } from '@ngui/tab';
```

I looked for similar errors but couldn't find any solution until now, your help will be appreciated.

Comment: you need to add  import { NguiTabModule } from '@ngui/tab'; 
in component.ts also in which you are using.

Comment: I already imported it